# When I updating my pip，I meet an error：“NameError: name '_main_' is not defined”

Tags: python

When I updating my pip，I meet an error：`NameError: name '_main_' is not defined`

```py
C:\Users\16214>python -m pip --upgrade pip
File "D:\Python3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main 
 "__main__", mod_spec)
File "D:\Python3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
 exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
 sys.exit(_main_.main())
NameError: name '_main_' is not defined
```

Can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: How many versions of python do you have in your system. and are you using anaconda or some other environment

Comment: There are no other environment in my system, and I just have python3 in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. 
There is a mistake in my `\pip\__main__.py` file.
I found pip's repository on github and compared my `__main__.py` file.
In my file，there is a piece of code like this:

```
from pip._internal import main as _main_  # isort:skip # noqa
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(_main_._main())
```

But on github, it is like this:

```
from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(_main())
```

After I modified my code, I solved this problem.

Comment: If this answers your question, please select it as the accepted answer by clicking on the tick under the voting buttons.

Comment: My distro has on first line of `/usr/local/bin/pip3` `from pip._internal.cli.main import main` and then I put `sys.exit(main())`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this in cmd as admin:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

if not try
opening CMD in the python folder
like 
C:\Python27

```
C:\Python27>python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then run the above command in cmd as admin.

Comment: Thanks for your help！But I still meet this error when I running as admin. Maybe there's something wrong with my pip. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: This isn't a priveledge issue - It would raise a `WinError: Access Denied` or something similar. This is an error with the pip/python build.

Comment: I installed `pip` with `apt install python3-pip` and get the error, so your answer probably does not help.